# Which animations will work on Keynote export to PowerPoint?

Tags: ms-office, keynote, iwork

I have a *Keynote* (iWork 9) presentation and need to export it as PowerPoint. When doing it using *File : Export : PPT* the slides work properly, but most of the animations are broken.

Is there a animations compatibility list for exporting to PowerPoint? I found an old [apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5592) discussing the import, but nothing about export. Ok, I can assume some animation assignments from that article, but it is also marked as *no longer updated*.

Does anybody has a source for a full list? Or one based upon experience?

Answer (score -3):

Check this page out: https://blog.udemy.com/keynote-to-powerpoint/ Hope this helps!

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: No, there is nothing about animation compatibility except that Keynote has others then PPT, ok nothing new.